# PyPlot stops plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time

I am reading some values from a txt file and am plotting those points using pyplot. The code is given below:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            print 'hi'
            val=line.split()
            x=300+float(val[0])
            y=300+float(val[1])
            plt.plot(x, y, 'b.', markersize=1)
            plt.draw()
            plt.show()
```

This function is plotting the points correctly. The problem is, it stops in between, randomly. The `print` statement I put was to check if the for loop is executing or not, it is as **hi** is printed again and again.

Where am I going wrong? Why does it stop plotting randomly?

Comment: Why are you plotting it like this? Why don't you put `x` and `y` in arrays and then plot them outside the loop just once?

Comment: The ultimate plan is to get real time values from some server and plot them real time. That's why this method, I will just get two values and plot them.

Comment: See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766100/real-time-matplotlib-plot-is-not-working-while-still-in-a-loop?rq=1 as well as the comments left there

Comment: It works! The only problem is it closes automatically when the plot is completed. How do I stop that?