# Dynamically updating plot with watchdog

Tags: matplotlib, watchdog

Whenever a new txt file is added to a directory, I would like to plot and show the data from the file. If another file appears, I want the plot to update and show the new data. Creating a plot outside the main caused thread errors, so I made a (not very good) fix using global variables.

The problem is that a white figure appears and the plots do not show. After stopping the program, the white figure disappears and the plot appears. The correct image is saved to file, but I would like the image to be shown in real time. If I comment out the plt.show(), no plots appear.

I tried the "Dynamically updating plot in matplotlib" answer ([Dynamically updating plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944621/dynamically-updating-plot-in-matplotlib)) but found that because it never called show(), no window appeared. If I tried calling show(), it blocked updates.

Inserting plt.pause() did not work ([Real time matplotlib plot is not working while still in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766100/real-time-matplotlib-plot-is-not-working-while-still-in-a-loop))

The example code did not work ([How to update a plot in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib/4098938#4098938))

Here is my code:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import config

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns=["*.txt", "*.TXT"]

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def process(self, event):
        filename = event.src_path
        if '_AIt' in filename:
            config.isnew=True
            config.fname=filename


if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path='.', recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    dat=[0,1]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    Ln, = ax.plot(dat)
    ax.set_xlim([0,10])
    ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()    

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            if config.isnew:
                config.isnew=False

                dataarray = np.array(np.transpose(np.loadtxt(config.fname)))
                dat = dataarray[15] #AI0
                Ln.set_ydata(dat)
                Ln.set_xdata(range(len(dat)))
                plt.savefig(config.fname[:-4] + '.png', bbox_inches='tight')
                plt.draw()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

config.py (creates default values of the configuration setting)

```
isnew=False
fname=""
```

I am confused because the following example code works well (from [pylab.ion() in python 2, matplotlib 1.1.1 and updating of the plot while the program runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro/12826273))

```
import pylab
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dat=[0,1]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
Ln, = ax.plot(dat)
ax.set_xlim([0,20])
ax.set_ylim([0,40])
plt.ion()
plt.show()    

for i in range (18):
    dat=np.array(range(20))+i
    Ln.set_ydata(dat)
    Ln.set_xdata(range(len(dat)))
    plt.pause(1)

print 'done with loop'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you want:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()  # enter interactive mode
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
Ln, = ax.plot(dat)
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
plt.draw()  # non-blocking drawing
plt.pause(.001)  # This line is essential, without it the plot won't be shown

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if config.isnew:
            ...
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(.001)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

The essential thin is to call `plt.pause` after the `plt.draw` call, else it won't be drawn, as the other python code block `matplotlib`. The value `.001` is simply a try. I don't really know how it works under the hood, but this seems to work.

Comment: If anyone else struggles with this: it is essential to move the plotting out of the on_created function and into the While True - loop