# Plotting values From a Array in Real time using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, real-time

I'm wanting to plot the size of two arrays I have in my python program. Im wanting these to be plotted in real time while the program is running. Ive been trying to do this but due to lack of experience in matplotlib i'm struggling doing this. Could anyone help me with writng this code. The Names of the arrays are Arr_Particle1 and Arr_Particle2.

Thanks! :)

Comment: This question has been asked many times already, please search the old questions first.

Comment: see here also https://gist.github.com/electronut/5641933

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822762/pylab-ion-in-python-2-matplotlib-1-1-1-and-updating-of-the-plot-while-the-pro/12826273#12826273

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647491/figure-gui-freezing/14649216#14649216

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265513/matplotlib-real-time-linear-line/14266609#14266609

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791722/can-you-plot-live-data-in-matplotlib/18793416#18793416

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679013/python-1-second-plots-continous-presentation/12682987#12682987

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665636/time-sleep-required-to-keep-qthread-responsive/14666811#14666811

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. I tried that code and after downloading the six python module it worked